# Can "at" command execute any kind of shell script?

Tags: shell-script, at

I created a java program that showed a message dialog. After pressing OK it is closed and the program execution ends.

Then I created a shell script `alarm.sh` that executed the program. I tested it and it worked:

```
$ alarm.sh "-i It's time to ring up the revenue service"
```

However when I executed:

```
$ echo "alarm.sh \"-i It's time to ring up the revenue service\"" | at 15:00
```

The message dialog didn't pop-up at 15:00 although the job was scheduled. Why? How does "at" execute shell scripts and what are its limitations?

Comment: `at` using its own environment which doesn't contain `DISPLAY` which is required for x11 applications.

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. I think this should be the answer.

Comment: See [How can I use an at command in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454199/how-can-i-use-an-at-command-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `at` can only run non interactive scripts.

These scripts will be run without being attached to the terminal from where you launched the `at` command. If the program outputs something in its `stdout` and/or `stderr` flow, this output will be sent to you by mail.

Some variables are not retained when the script is launched, especially `DISPLAY`, which is the reason why your attempt failed. You might have a look to your mail to see if the error is reported. If not, `sendmail` or similar is probably not installed/configured.

If you want to use the current X11 display when the command will be run, you can set it that way:

```
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY alarm.sh \"-i It's time to ring up the revenue service\"" | at 15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`at` might not have whatever your current working directory is as *its* working directory.  Specify the complete path to `alarm.sh`:

```
echo "/path/to/alarm.sh '-i There is no alarm; only Zuul'" | at 15:00
```